# Ubuntu can't using samba LAN sharing when using Android tethering

Tags: networking, ubuntu, android, samba, tethering

When I using two pc(both Ubuntu) connect to my Android phone's network, one from USB tethering and one from Wifi hotspot, I can't see samba Lan sharing folders. I tried to find IP address of both devices and here's the result

```
192.168.42.74/24 (USB tethering)
192.168.43.7/24 (Wifi hotspot)
```

Both devices under the same Lan, right?
from my phone file explorer I can see PC using Wifi hotspot samba sharing folders. But USB tethering devices never appeared.

Comment: They are on different subnets.

Comment: @DavidPostill Then how to make Samba works under different subnets?